# Junos pulse and share internet connection by ad-hoc Wi-Fi on OS X

Tags: macos, ios, network, vpn, internet-sharing

### Basic problem

If I run Pulse secure (or Junos Pulse) on my iOS device, this breaks functionality of TCP socket in background. I mean if application is in background it can't be woken up by incoming data if VPN client is running.

### First workaround

As a workaround I shared internet connection from my Mac via ad-hock Wi-Fi which was running VPN client to my iOS device. In such case iOS device was not running VPN client and TCP sockets was working when application was in background.

### Final problem

When I had OS X 10.10 it was working Ok, but after an upgrade to OS X 10.11 internet connection is shared but without network hidden behind a VPN connection.

In configuration file: `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat.plist` I can see that internet connection is shared from network device *en0* to *en1*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>NAT</key>
        <dict>
                <key>AirPort</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>40BitEncrypt</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                        <key>Channel</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                        <key>Enabled</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                        <key>NetworkName</key>
                        <string>MyAdhockNetwork</string>
                        <key>NetworkPassword</key>
                        <data>
                        </data>
                </dict>
                <key>Enabled</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NatPortMapDisabled</key>
                <false/>
                <key>PrimaryInterface</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>Device</key>
                        <string>en0</string>
                        <key>Enabled</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                        <key>HardwareKey</key>
                        <string></string>
                        <key>PrimaryUserReadable</key>
                        <string>Ethernet</string>
                </dict>
                <key>PrimaryService</key>
                <string>AFFBAE8A-79CE-4710-9772-F0E8750F9292</string>
                <key>SharingDevices</key>
                <array>
                        <string>en1</string>
                </array>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Changing this setting from *en0* to *utun0* (network device introduced by VPN client) didn't solve the problem: service is unable to start.

In "Settings/Sharing" it is impossible to configure internet sharing so *utun0* would be used since combo box "Share your connection from:" doesn't have an entry which could match this device.

Any thoughts how can I solve one of the above problems? The main aim is to restore ability to receive data by application in background (it has SIP capabilities).

Comment: Please improve your question because some settings & configs are unclear! 1st workaround: The Mac was connected with a VPN client via Ethernet to a VPN server and this connection was shared via WLAN to the iPhone? Additionally ad-hoc WLANs aren't encrypted anymore in OS X 10.11! So the plist won't work anymore...